# VBA Excel Не срабатывает Call

Tags: vba

Есть вот такой участок кода. Здесь по идее каждую итерацию цикла должен вызываться Sub writeStats, но этого не происходит. Проверяя через F8, увидел, что цикл просто вхолостую прогоняется. Параметры все сохраняются корректно, код исправно работал до сегодняшнего дня. Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, и все работает как надо, а ошибку надо искать в другом месте?

```
For i = 0 To UBound(rangeList)

    Call writeStats(active.Cells(i + 2, nameOfStat), _
    active.Cells(i + 2, employeeOfStat), _
    active.Cells(i + 2, stadyOfStat), _
    active.Cells(i + 2, categoryOfStat), _
    active.Cells(i + 2, categoryOfFinance))
    
Next i

End Sub

Sub writeStats(name, employee, stage, category, finance)

  Dim bl As Boolean
  Dim categ As Long
```

Comment: Начните с простого пересоздания функции - т.е. удалите полностью и создайте заново. Может, даже переместите в отдельный common-модуль (тогда не забудьте приписать ей Public). Если не вылечит - пересоздайте по той же схеме весь модуль.

Comment: Перенес функцию в отдельный модуль, не помогло. Проверил в отдельном файле подобную этой примитивную функцию из цикла, все работает. Может слишком большой код, но тогда бы ошибку выдавало. В общем я не знаю.

Comment: *Может слишком большой код* В одном модуле? бывало и такое (ну или похожее - не у меня, а в форумах читал), дели на части... да, знаю случаи, когда только перенос кода и данных в новый файл лечил подобное поведение.

Comment: Еще попробовал вызвать другую простую функцию из этого цикла, и она запустилась. То есть проблема именно в writeStats или ее параметрах.

Comment: Разобрался, дело было в параметре finance, в который ничего не записывалось, и который не давал запускать функцию.

Comment: ??? У функции 5 параметров, ровно столько и передаётся. Неважно, пустой параметр или нет - функция должна была вызываться.

Comment: *цикл просто вхолостую прогоняется* - это как? Не передавал управление внешней процедуре? А если передавал, то *"дело было в параметре finance, в который ничего не записывалось"*  - это может быть причиной только в том случае, когда в вызываемой процедуре недопустимо применение переменной без записанного значения

Comment: да, на строке с вызовом функции цикл не останавливался и переходил к следующей итерации.
не знаю, почему не работало, вроде все указано корректным образом, просто значение = 0 и в самой функции этот finance ни разу не применялся